# Issue with Scrolling on HTML

Tags: html, css, glitch-framework

**Issues I have had**

- I have not been able to scroll down on my site.
- No solutions I ave found work.

**Info**

- My site is execlinux.glitch.me
- The CSS files and HTML can be found by going to glitch.com and searching execlinux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the css below is incorrect:

```
.text {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

You could try changing *fixed* to *relative*, however if you do there will be other issues you will face.

If you use the following css:

```
.text {
      position: relative;
      top: 100px;
      left: 50px;
    }
```

you will find that the contents of your <*div class="text"*> scrolls over the top of your navigation menu and is not left justified.

Perhaps try

```
.text {
          position: relative;
          top: 100px;
          left: 50px;
          z-index-1;
          width: 90%;
      }

 html {
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          overflow: visible;
      }
```

Tested these changes and while not perfect, they achieve a somewhat satisfactory result.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution:

in your CSS file you have a ".text" element which has the fixed position property. It's wrong!!! it should have the relative position like the below:

```
.text {
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50px;
}
```